# Activiti - Get groovy variables within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, groovy, alfresco, activiti

I have a groovy script that creates a map of tasks that I want to display within a user form:

```
Map<String,String> tasks = new HashMap<String,String>();
tasks.put("task 1","this is a new task");
tasks.put("task 2","this is another new task");
```

This is fine and allows me the ability to reference the `tasks` variable throughout my process model. But how do I iterate through this map in the user form using JavaScript?

I thought I might be able to reference the `tasks` variable within the user form in a Display text control like this:

```
All tasks: ${tasks}
```

But the `tasks` variable is empty.

Im fairly new to Activiti so please excuse me if this a simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will return the Map as a JSON, It will be good to that read / parse in javascript.

```
Map<String,String> tasks = new HashMap<String,String>();
tasks["task 1"] = "this is a new task";
tasks["task 2"] = "this is another new task";
println tasks.dump()
// return / render the above map task to java script or you can return that as a JSON.
```

In javascript you can iterate the map elements and show, parse if it is rendered as a JSON.

Comment: So the json variable will be returned as a string right? Ill give this a try. How would I then iterate over it using a form control though? Would i need to write a custom control to parse the json?

Comment: You will receive that as a json object just, find the values using key and update your form DOM values